# GWT/Gradle project examples.

Tags: java, gwt, gradle

I need advice on how to structure a multi-tier GWT/Spring project so that Gradle can build the artifacts and deploy the correct jars..

Google hasn’t helped much – I can find a number of articles on building multi-projects and indeed building GWT project in Gradle however, all of these seem incomplete for my problem domain as I’m finding the following problems as I have encountered the following issues.

1. In the multi-project examples, the GWT dependencies are being included in the web-application from the war plug-in.
2. If I go down the single gradle build route then I’m losing decoupling with the projects..
3. Both the client & Server have dependencies on certain class files (for GWT-RPC); currently these are packaged in the client project so has resulted, again, in a server dependency on the client (for the GWT-RPC DTO objects).. This leads me to feel  I need a third module exclusively for the shared class files with the source being also present in the gwt-client project (for the GWT compiler to pick these up)..

So; the question is has anyone came across a multi-tier GWT examples that uses Gradle as the build tool &  deals with some/all of the above issues?

Thanks in advance,
Ian.

Answer (score 1):

We're using a single build, but we address point #2 - "coupling of projects" using the [Classcycle](http://classycle.sourceforge.net/) maven dependency plugin.

Ultimately, you want three genres of code: server, client and shared. The advantage of packaging those separately in separate jars (as you said in point #3) is that your server jar size will be decreased, and you could use more liberal source directories in your `.gwt.xml` file.

If you decide to use a single jar/war, then you will be including the extra, unused client classes on the server. This could lead to runtime exceptions from code leakage and (potentially?) worse performance on the server. We avoid the runtime exceptions by enforcing the layering separation at build time (using Classcycle), and the extra performance overhead from the extra client classes should be marginal. You can always strip out the client code from the jar after compile, using a post-build task.

Sorry, I don't know much about gradle, but I figured I would try to help anyways.

Comment: @Ian - No problem. The GWT build is inherently complicated due to having those "three genres" of code.